# struct as global variable

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

so if we declare and define a struct before main and want to use this struct in  other file which are in the same root as this one, do we need to declare it again in that file? Especially I want to share the memory of a array whose element is the struct so I need to use the shm_get in another file, do I need to declare those struct again?

btw, is it in C

code will be like this:

```
 typedef struct {
 char y1;
 char y2;
 char y3;
 int x;
 } itemB;

int main(){...
itemB* BufferB;
```

then i share the memory

```
shmem2 = shm_get(542421, (void**)&BufferB, 30*sizeof(itemB));
```

so if i write another file which want to share the BufferB, I know should declare one more time BufferB and call the shm_get again use the same initial key, but should I declare a struct one more time? and where?

Comment: You need to tag the language you are using.

Comment: And also share a bit of the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

The struct declaration does not have to be visible if you are only using a pointer to the struct, but it does need to be visible for `sizeof(itemB)` to work, or for you to be able to access any of the struct members by name.

If the struct definition is needed in multiple files then usually the definition is placed in a common file called a *header* which is `#include`d from the files which need to see the definition.

It would be possible to copy-paste the definition to wherever it is needed, but that runs the risk of one definition being updated without the other definition being kept in sync, which would violate the One Definition Rule.

Comment: so it is okay if I declare the struct before the main in every files that I need it or I can just put them in the main? @Matt McNabb

Comment: Your program must only have one `main` so that comment doesn't make sense

Comment: I have several files which run individual, but they only share  the specific memory which is the BufferB who contains the items. @Matt McNabb

Comment: @Echo OK, as explained in my answer, you *could* copy-paste the `itemB` definition to every file but it would be safer to put it in a common file such as `itemB.h` and do `#include "itemB.h"` before `main()` in each program